# Typescript/React ForwardRefExoticComponent assignment with more specific HTMLElement ref fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref

I am trying to write a HOC and type the children which you can pass to it.

the scenario looks somewhat like this (also in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-taussig-h2dpm?file=/src/App.tsx):

```js
interface HOCProps {
    modules: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
        HOCChildProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement>
    >[];
}
interface HOCChildProps {
    ...
}
declare const HOC: React.FC<HOCProps>;

// this produces an error in HOCTest if HTMLDivElement is used
// and an error in HOCChildTest if HTMLElement is used
// as the ref type in React.forwardRef
const HOCChildTest = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HOCChildProps>(
    (props, ref) => (
        <div ref={ref}>
            ...
        </div>
    )
);
const HOCTest: React.FC = () => <HOC modules={[HOCChildTest]} />;
```

the code is still working, but the typings are not.

it seems that this assignment fails:

```js
declare const divTest: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
>;

export const htmlTest: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement>
> = divTest;
```

The Typescript error message:

```
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>' is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RefAttributes<HTMLElement>>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'RefAttributes<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
```

In the last line it states that I am trying to assign `RefAttributes<HTMLElement>` to `RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`, but I do the assignment the other way round (as the first line correctly shows).

Am I missing out on something? Because I assumed that a component with a more specific HTMLDivElement ref would be assignable to a component with a more general HTMLElement ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the types of `ref` that can be forwarded by `forwardRef` is a callback ref.  If you've dealt with passing around callbacks then you'll know that `extends` is sort of "backwards" when dealing with a callback.  But `forwardRef` can also forward a `RefObject`.

Since you are dealing with the union of the object and the callback, you need to have the **exact** right type of ref.  It cannot be broader or narrower.

Here's some examples to clarify it:

```
// ok
const f = (ref: (instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) => <div ref={ref}/>

// ok
const f = (ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>) => <div ref={ref}/>

// ok because HTMLDivElement extends HTMLElement
const f = (ref: (instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) => <div ref={ref}/>

// error because HTMLElement is not assignable to HTMLDivElement
const f = (ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>) => <div ref={ref}/>

// error because a div ref can only be assigned to a div
const f = (Element: "div" | "a", ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>) => <Element ref={ref}/>

// error because we need a more exact ref type
const f = (Element: "div" | "a", ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>) => <Element ref={ref}/>

// ok - the only possible ref here must be both a div and an a
const f = (Element: "div" | "a", ref: MutableRefObject<(HTMLDivElement & HTMLAnchorElement) | null>) => <Element ref={ref}/>
```

I was expecting this to be an error and apparently it's not.

```
const f = (Element: "div" | "a", ref: (instance: (HTMLDivElement & HTMLAnchorElement) | null) => void) => <Element ref={ref}/>
```

So now I've stumbled upon a possible solution, which is that your ref can be an intersection of all of the individual ref types.

It's hard to say what the best solution is without knowing that `HOC` does.